# How can I Pass a Table Name to SqlCommand?

Tags: c#, ado.net, sqlcommand

I am trying to pass a table name as a parameter to my query through `SqlCommand` but it doesn't seems to be working. 
Here is my code;

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection( "server=.;user=sa;password=12345;database=employee" );
con.Open( );
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand( "drop table @tbName" , con );
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@tbName" , "SampleTable" );
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery( );
con.Close( );
```

Answer (score 10):

[`SqlCommand.Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are supported for *[Data manipulation language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language)* operations not *[Data definition language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language)* operations.

Even if you use DML, you can't parameterize your table names or column names etc.. **You can parameterize only your values**.

Data manipulation language =

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...
INSERT INTO ... VALUES ...
UPDATE ... SET ... WHERE ...
DELETE FROM ... WHERE ...
```

Data definition language =

```
CREATE TABLE ... 
DROP TABLE ... ;
ALTER TABLE ... ADD ... INTEGER;
```

You can't use [`DROP` statement](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879259.aspx) with parameters.

If you **really** have to use drop statement, you might need to use string concatenation on your `SqlCommand`. (Be aware about [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)) You might need to take a look at the term called [Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` like;

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
using(SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
   cmd.CommandText = "drop table " + "SampleTable";
   con.Open()
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: This isn't really a question of DML vs DDL: it would be equally problematic to insert a table name or a column name into a SELECT statement. SQL Parameters are simply limited to places you could put variables in SQL, and you can't use variables when referring to database objects.

Answer (score 4):

User Soner Gönül pointed out why it doesn't work, nevertheless you can write stored procedure yourself.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.procdroptable
    @TABLENAME SYSNAME
AS
 BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @SQL = 'DROP TABLE dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@TABLENAME) + '';
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
 END
GO
```

Code from [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39627/how-to-drop-tables-using-a-variable-in-sql-server).