# Update with Output (@MyTableVar), fails in C#, works fine in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, dataset

I am trying to run a query (using C#) that updates x number records in SQL Server and where I afterwards can loop through the updated records.

The query works fine in SQL Server Management Studio, but in C# code it fails with this error:

> Must declare the table variable "@MyTableVarSELECT"

Code:

```
string query =
       "DECLARE @MyTableVar table(ID varchar(50), Byy varchar(50))" +
       "UPDATE TOP (5) estae SET mp_used = '1'" +
       "OUTPUT inserted.mp.value1, inserted.mp_valye2 INTO @MyTableVar" +
       "SELECT * FROM @MyTableVar";

DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.Sql))
{
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

    conn.Open();
    adapter.Fill(dataset);
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: You can't use parameters in sql queries for table names in c#.

Comment: You need to add to your cmd a parameter called MyTableVar.  Do followng : SQlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn).  Then cmd.Paremter.Add()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I Pass a Table Name to SqlCommand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23357481/how-can-i-pass-a-table-name-to-sqlcommand)

Comment: Wow; 3 totally invalid comments; sorry, but this has nothing to do with parameterized table names

Comment: @Allcam - Can you use stored Procedure here and it is very straightforward  and do not need to  write complex c# logic in code.

Comment: @AbdulAzeez stored procedures are also not a magic wand; the C# to invoke a stored procedure is virtually identical to the C# to invoke a correctly parameterized query - but with much easier deployment and flexibility.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is simply: whitespace.

Consider:

```
 string query =
        "DECLARE @MyTableVar table(ID varchar(50), Byy varchar(50))" +
        "UPDATE TOP (5) estae SET mp_used = '1'" +
        "OUTPUT inserted.mp.value1, inserted.mp_valye2 INTO @MyTableVar" +
        "SELECT * FROM @MyTableVar";
```

Those newlines **only exist in the C#** - the concatenated SQL string is all one line.

Options:

- add whitespace
- add semicolons
- add both

For the last:

```
string query = @"
DECLARE @MyTableVar table(ID varchar(50), Byy varchar(50));

UPDATE TOP (5) estae SET mp_used = '1'
OUTPUT inserted.mp.value1, inserted.mp_valye2 INTO @MyTableVar;

SELECT * FROM @MyTableVar;";
```

This should now work. The use of `@"..."` (a "verbatim string literal") allows us to use newlines etc inside the C# string. The semicolons make the individual commands in the TSQL more explicit so they don't bleed into each-other.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the query and not cause parameter confusion by just using `OUTPUT` to return the result set. Also, you don't need to open or close the connection if you use a `SqlDataAdapter`. I have attempted to correct your typos, I don't know if I got it right.

```
string query = "UPDATE TOP (5) estae SET mp_used = '1' OUTPUT inserted.mp_value1, inserted.mp_value2";

DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.Sql))
{
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    adapter.Fill(dataset);
}
```