# Send table name as a parameter in sql c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-6.0

I was able to send the id successfully but trying to parametrize the table name is not possible,
how can I solve this? or is there another way to send the table name as parameter in c# sql

```cs
    deleteCommand.CommandText = "delete from @tableName where rowid=@ID";
    deleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tableName", table.Name));
    deleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", table.id));
```

Comment: Does this code generate any exception? Please, post its stack trace if so.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I Pass a Table Name to SqlCommand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23357481/how-can-i-pass-a-table-name-to-sqlcommand)

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use string interpolation instead:

```
deleteCommand.CommandText = $"delete from {table.name} where rowid=@ID";
```

Comment: Depends on where the table.Name is coming from. If it's from an unsafe source, they could inject SQL  into the table name and mess things up pretty badly.

Comment: This is not ideal because the DML doesn't allow to parameterize table names or column names, but it works fine if you are aware of SQL Injection.