# C# SQLite: Can you use a parameter in place of a table name?

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, select, parameters

I have a database with tables that are similar in name and want to access their data based on a parameter.  The SQL string I am trying to use looks like this:

`string sql = "SELECT * FROM @table WHERE EntryID = @ID"`

and then have the parameter add the table name as such

`cmd.Parameters.Add("@table", DbType.String).Value = tableName;`

this is just pseudo for my actual code but this is a very close representation of what I am using.

Comment: Please see: [How can I Pass a Table Name to SqlCommand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23357481/how-can-i-pass-a-table-name-to-sqlcommand)

Comment: no, table names are one of the few places you can't use parameters; use a whitelist instead if your software design absolutely relies on this method and _is impossible to refactor_

Comment: I figured out a work around using switch and a function to execute the code based on the case values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, since you control the content of the string.

You can construct the string by adding the table name within.

Example:
`string sql = $"SELECT * FROM {tableName} WHERE EntryID = @ID"`

This is called [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#string-interpolation). I use a similar approach in my Base Classes for CRUD operations.

Edit:

There is mention that is is open to SQL injection. If the parameter named `tableName` in OP's example, is controlled by the developer and does not take user input, this is **safe**. If for some very odd reason the parameter takes user input, this can be open to SQL injection and should **NOT** be done.

Comment: That can open up sql injection attacks. In MS SQL Server I would use QUOTENAME to mitigate this, not sure if SQLite has anything like that.

Comment: @Marius: That is not a "parameter".  "Parameter" has a very specific meaning in the context of SQL.

Comment: I know what a parameter is. And he is not trying to use one. There should also be no user input to the `tableName` parameter, so SQL injection isn't possible. He is clearly controlling which table is used, not the user, and not with user based input.